# mongoose 4 InsertMany return undefined

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to use insertMany as stated in the latest mongoose doc :

**test.utility.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Groups from '../models/group.model';

const utils = {
  createMultipleGroups(n) {
    if (n > 26) {
      console.log('Cannot create more than 26 groups');
      return false;
    }
    const letters = 'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    const multiGroups = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
      multiGroups.push({ name: `Group${letters.charAt(i)}`, description: `Description Group${letters.charAt(i)}` });
    }
    console.log('UTILITY multiGroups array: %j', multiGroups);

// UTILITY multiGroups array
// [{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"}
//. {"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"},
// {"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}]

    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState); // 2 connecting !

    Groups.insertMany(multiGroups)
      .then((savedGroups) => {
        console.log('saved multi groups: ', savedGroups.length);
        return savedGroups;
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('error saving multi groups %j', e);
        return [];
      });
  },
```

This function is called from a mocha test in the before hook

**user.test.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import request from 'supertest';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import app from '../../../index';
import User from '../../models/user.model';
import utils from '../../helpers/tests.utility';

/**
 * root level hooks
 */
before(() => {
  const createdGroups = utils.createMultipleGroups(3);
  console.log('created groups: %j', createdGroups);  // undefined
});
```

but it does  not return anything .. and nothing in the console... from the test.utility console logs
and 'undefined' upon return in the user.test console log

where am I wrong ?

thanks for feedbacks

Comment: Did you call `mongoose.connect()`?

Comment: this piece of code is in a tests.utility.js file, called from a mocha tests before()  hook :  before(() => { const createdGroups = utils.createMultipleGroups(3);
  console.log('created groups: %j', createdGroups);});  the returned createdGroups get undefined ... 

the mongoose.connect() is called before..

Comment: Your comment does not reflect what's in your question. You say in your question that nothing is logged to console, but in your comment you state that "the returned createdGroups" is undefined. Those are two very different things.

Comment: added more code info in the question ... thanks

Comment: If the driver is a `connecting` state, and neither the `then` nor the `catch` callback get called within a reasonable amount of time, you should start debugging the database connection because it obviously can't be set up. Also, your utility function is async, but `before` isn't, but that's a different issue.

Comment: You're right it's due to the fact I'm calling it from the before hook...
I moved the utils.createMultipleGroups(3) inside a test ( after the describe ) and it runs well...  any link to get more information about that point ?  Add it as an answer so I can vote for it !! thanks

Comment: For Mocha, a starting point would be this: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: yes thanks .. I should rather use :  describe('hooks', function() {..} if I want it